# San Francisco and Roboto fonts in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I need to write an app that uses the San Francisco font on iOS https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_(sans-serif_typeface) and the Roboto font on Android.

I'm not sure if they are both native fonts currently used by Codename One.    If not, what should I do to use them as default fonts?    Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the native builtin fonts then Roboto will be used on Android and San Francisco will be used on newer iOS devices (older devices will use Helvetica Neue).

See this post which discusses the one caveat which is Italics where we don't use San Frsancisco: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-skins-san-francisco-font.html